# How can I parse my nested data in React to render in Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    responses: [],
    scores: [],
    values: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchQuestionAnswers();
  }

  fetchQuestionAnswers = () => {
   if (this.state.activeSupervisionId) {
    axios.get('/question/response/' + this.state.activeSupervisionId).then(res => {
     responses: res.data.data, scores: res.data.data.map((s) => s.score), values: res.data.data.map((v) => v.value), loading: false
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
   }
  }

  render() {
     console.log(this.state.responses[0].value)
// dot notation not working here under render function but the result of // console.log(this.state.responses[0]) is printed
    return (  
                  <div className="pdf-table-container">
                    <table className="pdf-table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="id-col">Id</th>
                            <th className="text-col">Question</th>
                            <th className="score-col">Score</th>
                            <th className="value-col">Value</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr className="">
                            <td className="text-center">1</td>
                            <td className="text-left">Staff living in the residential quarter</td>
                            <td className="text-center">{scores[0]}</td>
                            <td className="text-left">{values[0].staffLivingInQuarter}                         </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Home;
```

I fetch a data from an API that was sent as array of objects. So lets say I set the state of `responses: res.data.data`.  The result of responses console appear as described below.

```
(143) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

I will use the 0 index object as an example of data received.

```
0: {
  id: 5,
  questionId: 1,
  score: "0",
  text: "Are there any others",
  value: {
    designations: {
      CCO: { no: "3" },
      CDD: { no: "1" },
      DSNO: { no: "1" }
    },
    reaportedStaff: [ "DSNO", "CCO", "CDD" ]
    staffLivingInQuarter: "yes"
    totalReaportedStaff: 5
  }
}
```

When I console the result of the mapped value I got:

```
values (143) [{…}, {…}, {…}, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', {…}, {…}, 'yes', 'no', 'yes', {…}, {…}, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', {…}, 'yes', {…}, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', {…}, 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', {…}, 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', …]
```

In the render function and the returned table I can access the yes and no value. But when I use dot for the object values I got undefined. Meanwhile the dot notation work if  console it in the function where I fetched the data.

console.log('values', values[1]) return `values {male: '4', child: '6', total: 9, female: '5'}`. But if I do `values[1].male` I got error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'male')`

Comment: hey! it looks youre getting values now! Try mapping over the values and adding their contents in a <p> tag to see if they show up

Comment: thanks @about14sheep I mapped over the res.data.data but was getting the error ```Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {designations, reaportedStaff, totalReaportedStaff, staffLivingInQuarter})```. It appears I have to parse value data inside the response as it contains object

Comment: its because you are trying to set the text inside a div to an object. Just to see if you're getting the values, try `{this.state.responses[0].value.totalReaportedStaff}` as the text content of the div

Comment: I thought I can do ```{responses.map((s, index) => (<Table>...</Table>)``` and try getting the value of responses but it is not working as React cant render the value object inside a table.

Comment: if you post the code you used inside the table tags we can try and debug it, also did you do what i mentioned above and get a result?

Comment: I added the table and how I use it

Comment: if you remove the s.value cell does it work?

Comment: I would make a new component, have it handle what to do with every response, and them map over the responses array feeding each response into the component through props

Comment: react wont let you put an object where it expects a string. I bet if you did JSON.stringify(s.value) it would have it, just really ugly

Comment: Yeah it pass but its really ugly

Comment: perfect, so all you need to do is place those values inside a cell individually. Like you did with the values at the root of the object. Just destructor the .value object as well

Comment: That is really a big task as the report has up to 143 questions and I have two others with up to 200 questions each. I am auto generating the report in a pdf after it is fetched. Thanks for the tip. It helps a lot

Comment: @Wacademy how do you want the `value` to be rendered?

Comment: @maazadeeb like a nested value where it is not a string

Comment: Do you mean a tree like structure that lets you expand and collapse? Or you just want it to be pretty-printed?

Comment: pretty printed as it is being used in a page converting to pdf

Comment: Would using `JSON.stringify(s.value, null, 4)` solve your problem? It just pretty prints JSON.

Comment: Sorry I slept off. It was tiring. I  ```JSON.stringify(s.value, null, 4)``` will not work for my solution as its still not pretty enough and its taking too much space. I will prefer the option to use dot notation to access the values of the nested object so as to manually build the table. Currently, inside render I still can't go beyond the first data level i.e ```responses[0]```.

Comment: I opted for react-json-tree package